# Need magento store id using store name

Tags: magento-1.8, websites

I want to get the Magento Store id using Store Name as Search.

I tried below code but failed.

```
$vendortitle = $vendortitle . " Store";
$name = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($vendortitle)->getStoreId();
echo "<br>Store Name> ". $name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$vendortitle = 'Store Title Here';
$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('name', $vendortitle);

$store = $collection->getFirstItem();
if ($store->getId()) {
    //the store exists
}
else {
    //the store does not exist.
}
```

But be careful. Theoretically you can get more than one record in the collection if you have 2 stores with the same name.

Comment: Glad it worked. Welcome to SE. When an answer to a question you asked solves your problem, mark it as accepted. This way we keep the website healthy.